# LibGdx Ecclipse Export Is Throwing an Excetion

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

as stated in the Headline I do find my self having problem exporting a libgdx Project of mine: (Excuse if all the pics are external I don't have permission to post them and it really simplifies describing my Problem.)
I first right-click on My Desktop Project click on Export an then I set it up like this:

I select the src of both projects and the assets of the desktop one. I just use the .classpath and the .project and the build.gradle from the desktop Project.

[image]

then I set the MainClass to my DesktopLauncher and then I try to run it with cmd and java -jar my.jar
and this Exception gets thrown:

[image]
I hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance

Felix

Comment: Please add the text of the picture link to the question. It is a site with pop-ups too.

Comment: Did change it to the direct pic links.

Comment: Better, but should provide all information directly to the question. I have quick fixed your screenshot. Now, paste the stacktrace to the question instead of the second image.

Comment: Is it fine like that?

Comment: It is better. :) But you should copy-paste the stacktrace.

Comment: whats the stacktrace?

Comment: The text what you see in the second image is called as  stack trace. I would recommend beginner to Google before asking question as  I believe experts have better job to do than answering silly questions. Note that I'm a  beginner..!

Comment: Now quesyion to you. Can you open your jar file using 7zip or win zip and check whether  you have "bin" folder with all .class files

Comment: Yes i can open it using WinRar